# Drawing strings in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using below method to draw string.

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSString *mName = @"Hi what are you doing";
    [mName drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,100,12) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter]
}
```

Is it possible to draw to "Hi" in different font, "what" in different font in iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `drawAtPoint:withFont:` for drawing of each word. You must compute the position of each drawn string. This can be done with `sizeWithFont:`-method. For example:

```
NSString* firstString = @"Hi ";
NSString* secondString = @"what";
// where to draw
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
CGFloat offset = [firstString sizeWithFont:font1].width + kSpaceBetweenWords;
// draw "Hi" with font1
[firstString drawAtPoint:position withFont:font1]; 
// draw "what" with font2
[secondString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(position.x+offset, position.y) withFont:font2];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to do two draw requests - one for each font - but that is rather trivial.

What is not trivial is to know where to place the text if the text is dynamic. In that case I would recommend subclassing UIView and the drawRect method and just draw it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

NSAttributedString is available for iOS 3.2 later. you can try this. Or else core text library is there to achieve the same...

Comment: My app deployment target is 3.0... so i can't use that.

Comment: Can you post the sample example to convert above string using core text library .

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW18